# How to reuse a matrix for feColorMatrix in SVG image

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I want to use a feColorMatrix primitive multiple times in one filter element. What changes is the x-coordinate, everything else stays the same. How do I do this in a DRY way?

Comment: You don't, you repeat it.

Comment: Ok, can be done using javascript of course, but this just does not appeal to me as very elegant http://jsfiddle.net/25s8qwz1/

Comment: Filters are not very elegant. In fact, they're primitives.

Comment: What is your suggestion then?